# Why are my inputs not resetting?

Tags: html, angularjs

The below code generates several forms depending on data returned from the server.  Everything generates fine, but after clicking on an AnswerOpenQuestion button the input does not clear/reset.  What's going on here?

angularJs code:

```
var availableInterviewController = function($scope, $http) {

// define initial model
$scope.interviews = [];

// retrieve available interviews
$http.get('/api/UserInterviewsApi/AvailableInterviews')
    .success(function(data) {

        // update interviews
        $scope.interviews = [];
        $scope.interviews = data;
    });

// define open question answer selection
$scope.Answer = "";

// define multiple choice selection
$scope.selectedChoice = "";

// define answer open question button
$scope.AnswerOpenQuestion = function() {
    $scope.Answer = ans;
    alert(q.Question + ' and ' + $scope.Answer);
    $scope.Answer = ''; // <---This is not clearing/resetting the HTML form inputs
};

// define answer multiple choice button
$scope.AnswerMultipleChoice = function() {
    // 
};
};

 // assign the new controller to the main angular app
 myAngApp.controller('availableInterviewCtrl', availableInterviewController);
```

Html code:

```
        <form class="form-group" ng-repeat="q in inter.Questions">
        <fieldset style="display: inline-block;">
            <legend>Question {{$index + 1}}</legend>

            <!--Open Ended-->
            <div class="form-group" ng-show="q.MultipleChoices.length === 0">
                <label for="{{'quest-' + $index}}">

                    <strong class="text-info">{{q.Question}}</strong><br />

                </label>
                <input name="openQuestion" id="{{'quest-' + $index}}" type="text"
                       class="form-control" ng-model="Answer" />

                <button ng-click="AnswerOpenQuestion()">Answer</button><br />
                <span class="text-info">
                    asked by {{q.AskedByUserName ==
                    'Administrator' ? 'staff' : q.AskedByUserName}}
                </span>
            </div>


            <!--Multiple Choice Question-->
            <div class="form-group" ng-show="q.MultipleChoices.length > 0">
                <label for="{{'quest-' + $index}}">
                    <strong class="text-info">{{q.Question}}</strong>

                </label>

                <div>
                    Select an answer:
                    <label ng-repeat="x in q.MultipleChoices">
                        <input name="currentChoice" type="radio" value="{{x.Id}}"
                               ng-model="selectedChoice" />
                        {{x.Choice}}
                    </label>

                    <button ng-click="AnswerMultipleChoice()">Answer</button><br />
                    <span class="text-info">
                        asked by {{q.AskedByUserName ==
                        'Administrator' ? 'staff' : q.AskedByUserName}}
                    </span>
                </div>

            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

**UPDATE - Solution**

AngularJs:

```
// define open question answer selection
$scope.OpenAnswer = { Answer: '' };

// define answer open question button
$scope.AnswerOpenQuestion = function (q, ans) {
    $scope.OpenAnswer.Answer = ans;

    alert(q.Question + ' and ' + $scope.OpenAnswer.Answer);

    // clear the input
    $scope.OpenAnswer.Answer = '';
};
```

Html:

```
<input id="{{'quest-' + $index}}" type="text"
                       class="form-control" ng-model="OpenAnswer.Answer" />
```

Comment: You mean the input tags with `ng-model` as `selectedChoice` and `selectedAnswer`?

Comment: as @callmekatootie put it - you don't have any of your input fields bound to that scope property, so either you're missing some HTML in your question or, you have your answer...

Comment: yeah sorry that was a mistake on my part. I updated the ng-model in the html. So with the ng-model as Answer, when the form is ran the first time it clears out all the other inputs except the active input. When I try to submit again, nothing is cleared out.

Comment: What is 'ans' and where is it defined? Also, do you see the alert in your submit?

Comment: See answer below, on phone so I kept it short let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the scope as a model instead make an object that wraps the data model and assign it to a property of the scope.

```
$scope.myModel = {Answer:''}
```

Also don't use value in most cases ngmodel is all you need for two way binding.

In js strings are immutable so the original reference is not being updated instead a new string is being made, the digest cycle won't see this as a change to the original string.

Comment: shaunhusain, that absolutely fixed it thanks.  But on another note I think that I may be going about this the wrong way. As I am generating many forms, I now realize that typing in one input will echo in all the other inputs.  How can I prevent this?

Comment: You are probably running into problems with the various parts sharing a $scope, each will need it's own ng-controller defined so there is an instance of the controller and new scope for each of the forms.